# Editable table not working

Tags: javascript, html

I made a table that you can add text to and edit it inside it.
However if you add more than three rows, It is stuck and not working anymore.

The errors comes from here:
document.getElementById('vda' + z).addEventListener('click', doSomething);
  document.getElementById('cvda' + z).addEventListener('click', doSomething2);

It is only adding event listener to the last row added, so if you add more than one row. The not last row won't have a working edit button.

I checked the IDs by inspecting the edit and update buttons elements.
Try adding 3 rows then click on the edit button for one of the row.
you can look at the code here and also https://jsfiddle.net/3e6d4qsv/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<style>
  table, th, td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  th, td {
      padding: 5px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="display:inline-flex;">
<form id="myForm">
<input id="inptext" type="text" placeholder="Your name..."></input>
<input id="inpadress" style="margin-left: 10px;" type="text" placeholder="Your email..."></input>
</form>
<button  onclick="myFunction()"style="margin-left: 10px;" id="box">Add</button>
</div>
<br>
<div style="display: inline-flex">
<table id="tablename" style="width:80%; margin-top:15px;">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="buttons" style="float:right;width: 300px; margin-top:50px;">
</div>
</div>


<script> 
var z = 1;
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("inptext").value;
  var y = document.getElementById("inpadress").value;
  var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
  form.reset();
  document.getElementById("tablename").innerHTML = document.getElementById("tablename").innerHTML  + '<tr><td id=acvda'+ z + '>' + x + '</td><td id=zcvda' + z + '>' + y + '</td></tr>';
  var h = '<button style="margin-left:8px" class="edit" id=vda' + z + '>Edit</button>';
  var f = '<div id=zzza'+z+' style=height:10px></div>';
  var abc = '<button style="margin-left:-36px" class="update" id="cvda'+z+'">Update</button>';
  var total = h + abc + f;
  document.getElementById("buttons").innerHTML = document.getElementById("buttons").innerHTML + total;
  document.getElementById('vda' + z).addEventListener('click', doSomething);
  document.getElementById('cvda' + z).addEventListener('click', doSomething2);
  document.getElementById('cvda' + z).style.visibility='hidden';
  z =  z + 1;
}
function doSomething() {
    document.getElementById("inptext").value = document.getElementById("ac"+this.id).innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("inpadress").value = document.getElementById("zc"+this.id).innerHTML;
    document.getElementById(this.id).style.visibility='hidden';
    document.getElementById('c'+this.id).style.visibility='visible';
}
function doSomething2() {
    document.getElementById("a"+this.id).innerHTML = document.getElementById("inptext").value;
    document.getElementById("z"+this.id).innerHTML = document.getElementById("inpadress").value;
    document.getElementById(this.id).style.visibility='hidden';
    form.reset();
    var edit = this.id;
    var edit2 = edit.replace("c", "");
    document.getElementById(edit2).style.visibility='visible';
}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've tried the fiddle and cannot reproduce the issue. I may add as much rows as i like...

Comment: transfer javascript to javascript part in jsfiddle

Comment: Same here, I tried the JSFiddle, its working as intended.
Can you check your console and let us know if it shows any errors?

Comment: The errors comes from here:
document.getElementById('vda' + z).addEventListener('click', doSomething);
  document.getElementById('cvda' + z).addEventListener('click', doSomething2);

It is only adding event listener to the last row added, so if you add more than one row. The not last row won't have a working edit button.

Answer (score 0):

The following line remove all your listeners:

> document.getElementById("buttons").innerHTML =
>   document.getElementById("buttons").innerHTML + total;
>   document.getElementById('vda' + z).addEventListener('click',
>   doSomething);

use this instead:

> var div = document.createElement('div');
>   div.innerHTML = total;
>   document.getElementById("buttons").appendChild(div);